# email Pipe to program: How to keep processing email or stop according to exit status?

Tags: email, pipe, filtering, cpanel

I made global filter in cPanel (InMotion Hosting) for mail:

```
TO: Contains
@something.com
Pipe to program:
$home/php/pipepiper.php
```

This works. pipepiper.php IS triggered when mail contains abc@something.com, however after triggering PHP script - mail processing stops and email IS NOT delivered to abc@something.com.

Is it possible to have some exit code inside pipepiper.php like:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
...
exit(777);
?>
```

Which means: Just go on and deliver mail to abc@something.com like I don't exist!

exit(0); or exit(1); behave same - processing stops and email IS NOT delivered to abc@something.com.

(Original e-mail is not changed in any way).